# How can I get my discord.js bots “Watching X users” status, to automatically update?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot status update automatically... example: if someone joins a server my bots in the status will update from x users to c users... here's what i tried, but it didn't work

```
bot.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log('I am ready!');
    
    setInterval(() => {
        bot.user.setActivity(`${bot.users.cache.size} users | +help`, { type: 'WATCHING' })
    }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: How doesn't your code work? Does it put the users as 0? or does it not set an activity at all

Answer (score 0):

You could have your bots activity update every time someone joins a guild instead of having to wait one minute for the activity to update.
Example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); //Define discord
const bot = new Discord.Client(); //Define bot

bot.on('ready', () => { //when the bot is ready
    console.log('I am ready!'); //Let you know that the bot is ready to be used

    bot.user.setActivity(`${bot.users.cache.size} users | +help`, { type: 'WATCHING' }); //Set a activity when ready
});

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => { //when someone new joins a guild
    bot.user.setActivity(`${bot.users.cache.size} users | +help`, { type: 'WATCHING' }); //Update the activity every time someone joins a guild
});
```

Comment: Activity update route is heavily ratelimited

Comment: However if you was just using the bot in one server your not expecting users to join 24/7 meaning that there will be at least a 20 second gap between each user.

Comment: @GlitchedTurtle no it sets the right member count but i want it to update itself... so if it was at 239 and someone joins a server it updates the status to 240